# VS2017 Constructor on type not found in WinForms Designer

Tags: c#, winforms, inheritance, constructor

I am trying to create a form that inherits from a form. The base class is called `Window`, and it inherits from `MetroForm`, which is a NuGet package that I've downloaded and installed on the project. This form loads without issue in the Designer.

```
public partial class Window : MetroForm
{
    public WindowType windowType { get; }
    public Engine engine { get; }

    public Window(WindowType windowType, Engine engine)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.windowType = windowType;
        this.engine = engine;
    }
}
```

The child form is declared and constructed as follows:

```
public partial class GraphicsWindow : Window
{
    public GraphicsWindow(WindowType windowType, Engine engine) : base(windowType, engine)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

It throws the following error in the designer window:

> "Constructor on type 'DispatcherDesk.Windows.Window' not found."

I've found multiple threads that address this error under the exact same circumstances, but none of the solutions are working for me. I've tried adding parameterless constructors to both the parent and child forms, adding `InitializeComponent();` calls to them, and using the `[Obsolete]` attribute and `private` access modifier. I've also tried rebuilding the solution and restarting Visual Studio at each step.

All I can figure at this point is that these solutions no longer work in VS2017, but I don't know why. Thanks in advance for any answers!

Comment: A base class must have a default constructor to be usable in the designer.  Simply because the designer has no way to figure out what arguments need to be passed.  So you *must* add `public Window()`.  Where necessary, add checks to the DesignMode property to discover that the form is being designed if might need to give up on runtime features.

Comment: I've tried that solution and still no success, unfortunately.